# How to get the first header child?

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to get the text that is inside h3. Here is my html:

```
<td id="something">
    <h3>Septembre 2014 Facebook</h3>
    <div>
         <h3>Comment</h3>
    </div>
    <table id="budget-channel-table">...
```

And here is my JQuery code:

```
$('#budget-channel-table').parent('#something').find('h3:first-child').text();
```

But My result is:

```
"September 2014 - Facebookcomment"
```

And I just need the first h3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the id is unique, you can use like this. Dont have to use `.parent()` or something th reach the element with an id.

```
$('#something > h3:first').text()
```

`>` selector will search for the immediate child only.

`find()` will search for all levels of children

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`:first`**](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), Also IDs must be unique you can simply use

```
$('#something').find('h3:first').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.children()` method. From the docs: *The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.*

```
$('#budget-channel-table').parent('#something').children('h3').text();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79zuwuk9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's .eq() http://api.jquery.com/eq/ so

```
$("#something h3").eq(0).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @AnoopJoshi has said, IDs are unique. Therefore you can use them as a reference and your search will be much faster. An alternate answer to @AnoopJoshi's is:

```
$('#something').children('h3').first().text()
```